# while loop doesn't stop, with if statement as nested loop in python

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, nested

The code doesn't stop even if 0 is fed as value. what could be the possible reason? see my code below:

```
x = -1
num = -9

print("For exit press 0")

while (x != 0):
    num = input("Enter a number  :")
    print("You entered: ", num)
    x = num
    if x == 0:
        break


print("Good bye!")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what language you're using. Looks like Python.

Comment: For me this works (if this is Python code). My Python 2.7.6 (OSX).

Comment: it worked with me, I just copied the code and run it and it works as expected, I'm on python 2.7

Comment: Python 2 and 3 probably treats string comparison differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing string to integer; Python is weakly typed, so no warning is given.

Additionally, `input()` casts the input in Python 2, but not Python 3. This is why the code works as intended in Python 2.

Notes:
You don't need parentheses for while condition.
Formatting the string is recommended for outputting things.

```
x = -1

print("To exit press 0")

while x != 0:
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    print("You entered: {}".format(num))
    x = int(num)
    if x == 0:
        break

print("Good bye!")
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that the only line I had to modify based on the clue from above answer is as follows:

    x = int(num)

I just added int() so that the numeric value goes into variable x, and it worked.